# Overlapping triangle and square puzzle

Tags: geometry

I've tried multiple ways to look at this, but I feel like there are too many variables to consider and I'm having a bit of a mental block. Help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is there any picture showing? If not, then this problem is probably undefined.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. This is all the information available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it implies that for the largest common area, so there's no difference whether the triangle would be on or under the square (let's imagine they are both transparent), then:

$S_0=\dfrac{2}{3}\times S_{square}=0.6\times S_{triangle}=\dfrac{3}{5}S_{triangle} $

$ S_{triangle} =\dfrac{10}{9}S_{square}=40$

Comment: Well, I think it is the answer.

Comment: AH! Thank you, I was misunderstanding. This really made it click. Feel quite stupid now... I'm going to blame the writing of the question.

Comment: Mathematician to mathematician, which triangle and square actually satisfies the conditions in the question?

Answer (score 1):

So I think both cases cover the same area since both look for optimization of coverage.

Thus: $\dfrac{2}{3} \cdot A_{\text{square}}=\dfrac{3}{5} \cdot A_{\text{triangle}}$

$A_{\text{triangle}}=\dfrac{2}{3} \cdot \dfrac{5}{3} \cdot 6 \cdot 6=40$